# Display world map raster in World Robinson projection in QGIS without the corners being repeated?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS version 3.2.3-Bonn on Windows 10.

I have downloaded the global physical map raster from Natural Earth [link](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-1/). This is in WGS84, and I wish to project it as World Robinson (ESRI:54030), but when I do so the map repeats in the corners (see screenshot). I wish to create a PDF without the corners being repeated. How can I do this?

I have tried:
 - Changing the project CRS to World Robinson and enabling 'On The Fly' projection.
 - Reprojecting the file to the World Robinson CRS, using raster -> projections -> warp (reproject).

Both approaches result in the corners of the map being repeated.

How can I simply show the map reprojected, without any part of the map being repeated?

[image: World map with CRS WGS84]
[image: Same map with World Robinson CRS (ESRI:54030). See repeated map portions in the corner]
[image: QGIS Print Composer has same issue of repeated map portions in the corner]

Answer (score 4):

Use the *gdalwarp* command to generate a new raster file reprojected to EPSG:54030.
You can find it in:
 - *Raster* menu, *Projections*, *Warp (Reproject)*.
or in
 - *Proccesing Toolbox*, *GDAL*, *Raster Projections*, *Warp (Reproject)*.

You can use the GUI:
[image: Warp]

The code is something like:
`gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:54030 -dstnodata 0.0 -r near -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:\NE1_LR_LC.tif C:\NE1_LR_LC-54030.tif`

You can adjust it to your needs, the result is something like this picture (black is no data):
[image: 54030]

Edit:
This is the result, the raster layer added, in QGIS Bonn
[image: Warped]

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel for your answer. Unfortunately, I tried: Raster menu, Projections, Warp (Reproject) in my original attempt. I have tried again and still get the same result. I.e. I reproject the original WGS84 raster into EPSG54030 but the corners are still reproduced, as in my original email. I have tried viewing the resultant files in both QGIS 3.2.3 and QGIS 2.18.14, and the corners are still being reproduced. Would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Reproject the image with *gdalwarp*, export the new raster layer, open the *.tif* file in some image viewer. The *.tif* file has the reproduced corners? If so, share the *gdalwarp* code and a link to the compressed image file. If not, create a new project and add the raster layer, there is no reason for QGIS to reproduce the corners in that case.