# How do I produce the cutoff seen in the Robinson projection in projections like Eckert IV?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In the Robinson projection, the world conforms to the projection as would be expected of a wall map, where it doesn't "wrap over" and show the other side of the world twice. Whenever I'm using the Eckert IV or Equal Earth projections, they wrap around and leave artifacts in the corners. I had found another post: [Display world map raster in World Robinson projection in QGIS without the corners being repeated?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304986/display-world-map-raster-in-world-robinson-projection-in-qgis-without-the-corner) but when I attempt to use the warp option it keeps the map as the same projection and only causes errors with missing spaces in the actual map. Is there something simple that I'm missing? I can't find any information on this googling or in the docs.

Edit: The command that I attempted to use is as follows (created from the GUI menu)

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs ESRI:54012 -dstnodata 0.0 -r near -of GTiff file.tif tempfile.tif

Comment: Please add the actual command you are using

Comment: Is there a reason as to why using the project properties menu to change the projection isn't sufficient? It works with the Robinson projection without the strange artefacts; there it snips off the corners and leaves the remaining map as you'd expect. With the Equal Earth and Eckert IV projections it does not do this. Is there something that needs to be done in the WKT or otherwise? I tried looking in there but it looks mostly the same in Robinson and Eckert IV.

Comment: The gdalwarp command works fine. To suit its visualization needs (paradoxically), QGIS changes a bit how to reproject rasters. If you export the raster layer to Eckert IV or Equal Earth from QGIS, the output is the same as the map reprojection, i.e., the corners are duplicated. If you apply the _Warp (reproject)_ process, they aren't. It can be fixed (it was fixed for the Robinson projection before). You can open an issue at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues.

Comment: Not sure if that helps? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/402125/88814